# Iterating through JSON data converted from multidimensional array

Tags: android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, apache-httpclient-4.x

**THIS WORKS FINE**

I have this code block to read a json data that I am getting from `FetchData.php` file; My code looks like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/mydummyproject/FetchData.php");
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
try {

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

    String name = object.getString("name");
    String verion = object.getString("version");
    textView.setText(name + " - " + verion);

} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Data from my PHP File `FetchData.php`

```
{"name":"John Doe","version":"Android 4.4"}
```

**PROBLEM**

I also have another type of data coming from `FetchDataTwo.php`

```
[{"name":"John Doe","version":"Android 4.4"}, {"name":"Seliana Gomez","version":"Android 4.1"}, {"name":"Nerdy Trumph","version":"Android 4.4"}]
```

Now the above one is also a json data that I have got by doing `json_encode($multidimensional_array)` in `PHP` file.

**ISSUE**

How to loop over this multidimensional encoded array from json. So that I can iterate over like this (json data by json data):

**[NOTE: Below is the data that I need to fetch, I don't want to arrange in the displayed fashion. That's just for clarity and example]**

```
Name          |    Version
John Doe      |    Android 4.4
Seliana Gomez |    Android 4.1
Nerdy Trumph  |    Android 4.4
```

Basically as a logic something like this:

```
//Loop over each json object

for data in JSONObject:

    // Print name and version
    textView.setText(data.name + " - " + data.version)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you have to do is iterate over the `JSONArray`

```
try {
    JSONArray array =  new JSONArray(inputString);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = array.optJSONObject(i);
        // Json Object handling...
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // handle
}
```

But really, using `Gson` should be way easier.  It can parse the contents for you into a simple java object.  You can annotate a POJO class with the field names and [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) does all the work.

```
public class NameVersionPair {

    private interface Json {
        String NAME = "name";
        String VERSION = "version";
    }
    @SerializedName(Json.NAME)
    private String mName;
    @SerializedName(Json.VERSION)
    private String mVersion;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return mVersion;
    }
}
```

Then use a `Gson` instance to parse your string automatically

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
NameVersionPair[] result = gson.fromJson(inputString, NameVersionPair[].class);
```